# Raspberry pi node: error while loading shared libraries: libl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, node.js

I have a raspberry pi 3 which has been running a node JS script using PM2 for 6 months without issues . However yesterday it stoped working and gives me the following error :

node: error while loading shared libraries: libl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

my node version is : 7.8.0 pis is running on : Linux raspberrypi 4.14.34-v7+ #1110 SMP Mon Apr 16 15:18:51 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

any ideas on  how to resolve it ? especially that I have another pi with the same setup running the same script for more than 6 months without issues

when running dmesg I get the follwoing highlighted in red :
[image]

Comment: have you performed any update recently? my guess is no, considering how old your kernel is, but in general, computers don't just change behaviour for no reason - perhaps your sdcard is failing ... check the output of dmesg

Comment: no it didnt do any updates  I searched for the issue but couldnt find any solution onlone

Comment: and ... the output of dmesg? any errors, especially regarding the SD card

Comment: how do i get that ?

Comment: you run `dmesg`

Comment: I'll update teh question with the result of dmesg as it long for a comment

Comment: well, they're nothing to do with the SD card. not anything to worry about either